# Is there a way to deal with error handling in a Async pipe in such a way that my GlobalErrorHandler does not pick up this error?

Tags: angular

I am struggling for a while with my GlobalErrorHandler and an Async pipe in a component template.

In the template of UserprofilesViewComponent:

```
<h2>Userprofiles</h2>
<ng-container *ngIf="userprofiles$ | async; else fail">
  <app-userprofile-list [userprofiles$]="userprofiles$"></app-userprofile-list>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #fail>
  <ng-container *ngIf="errorMessage$ | async as errorMessage">
    <h3>{{errorMessage}}</h3>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

In ngOnInit() of UserprofilesViewComponent:

```
// ...
this.userprofiles$ = this.userprofileService.getUserprofiles()
    .pipe(
      catchError((err:AppError) => {
      this.errorMessage$ = of(err.error.message);
      // return throwError(err);  // Error will propagate and be picked up by my GlobalErrorHandler
      return of([]);  // No erroring out, so no error picked up by my GlobalErrorHandler
    }),
    );
```

Btw, I have an HTTPInterceptor in place which is translating all HttpErrorResponse to AppError for all data services in my app. Thus, all services are receiving AppError objects instead of HttpErrorResponse.

Problem:

IF I rethrow the error in catchError `throwError(err)`, then the async pipe which has subscribed to userprofiles$ will error out. As expected in the code the else branch ('fail'-template) will be triggered for display (also the template rendering the list of userprofiles won't be showed --> this is my intent). Everything is working as I planned it to execute, but my GlobalErrorHandler is also triggered to handle the thrown error (throwError). I DO NOT WANT THE GLOBAL ERROR HANDLER TO TRIGGERED.

IF I do a replacement `of([])` as response to the occurred error, the `else branch` in template will not be triggered since there is no error (but rather a fallback result of an empty list). But, then the list of userprofiles will be rendered and no error message will be displayed on the page. THIS IS NOT WHAT I DESIRE IN BEHAVIOUR. In this situation my Global Error Handler will neither be triggered, because apparently no error has been thrown (catch-replacement pattern).

***In a nutshell:***

I am trying to figure out how I can impede the `async` to cause this situation. AFAIK, when the `async` pipe is applied to the observable `userprofiles$, it will subscribe and therefore will detect/trigger the thrownError. But apparently at this point in the template an unhandled error will occur and will` bubble up` until my registered GlobalErrorHandler will pick the error and handle it. I do not desire this to happen. So I am looking for a way for the GlobalErrorHandler not to handle this error.

Is there any pattern for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a custom global Error Handler by implementing the [ErrorHandler](https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler) interface.

> Your `GlobalErrorHandler` will intercept all the global exceptions
> arising in your code.

Even if you try to **return a new Observable** which errors out immediately, your `GlobalErrorHandler` will still catch it.

```
this.userprofiles$ = this.userprofileService.getUserprofiles()
    .pipe(
      catchError((err:AppError) => {
      this.errorMessage$ = of(err.error.message);
      return new Observable((subscriber) => subscriber.error(err));  // Error will still propagate 
    }),
    );
```

**Solution:**
Use  `return of([]);` in your `catchError` &
refactor your HTML a bit. Check for the array length after your async pipe is completed:

```
<h2>Userprofiles</h2>
<ng-container *ngIf="userprofiles$ | async as userList;">
  <app-userprofile-list *ngIf="userList && userList.length>0;else fail" [userprofiles$]="userprofiles$"></app-userprofile-list>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #fail>
  <ng-container *ngIf="errorMessage$ | async as errorMessage">
    <h3>{{errorMessage}}</h3>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```